# Why did Shane see those visions when he died?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In season 2 episode 12 of *The Walking Dead*, when Shane gets killed by Rick, Shane sees a vision of a bunch of walkers... Does this have any meaning? I've watched this show about 3 times now, but still don't understand this part...

I initially thought it was some sort of "brain washing" thing the viruses used, when I watched the show the first time around, the second time, I felt it was more just a random scene thrown in there and now, the third watch, I believe there may be a deeper meaning to it?

If there is, can someone please explain to me why Shane saw what he saw when he died? Does everyone see that when they die? Does just the viewer see that, and Shane didn't see a thing? What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Early on in the series, when the zombie contagion was still a relatively new concept to the audience, there were a couple of attempts to depict that a person near death could actually feel him/herself turning into a walker. The most prominent depiction was with Jim, the mechanic who was bitten in late Season 1. Jim became ill fairly quickly and the group placed him in the back of Dale’s RV on the bed. Jim made several statements that he knew he was dying and/or that he could feel the zombification process occurring in his body. While alone, and clearly worsening by the minute, Jim had visions of what looked like an up close encounter with a very aggressive walker. He would flinch when each vision occurred. It was subtly but very well depicted that Jim was turning and could feel the process beginning as he approached death.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear, but I believe those brief flashes were meant to foreshadow  Shane's rising again as a zombie.  To let us, the viewers, know that Shane was infected.

Remember, this scene came before the reveal (later in the episode - thank you BCdotWEB) that:

> Everyone is infected and everyone will rise again.

This particular detail wasn't taken for granted at the time of Shane's death scene.

Comment: The CDC is where *Rick* learned this, but the information was passed in a quick exchange that we didn't hear, IIRC.   He didn't share it with the others (or by extension the viewing audience) until later.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I stand corrected.  But this is still after Shane's death scene, correct?

Comment: Looks like it. I don't think I've watched the show post-S1 except for the odd episode, so it is possible I saw the S2 finale and mixed the two.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I don't blame you in the least... Not sure how that's relevant to my answer, though.

Comment: @Steve-O sorry, that was meant to be in reply to the comment above me. I’ll delete/reply correctly

Comment: @BCdotWEB yeah, you’re not missing much. I dropped the show after S6, because it got boring and repetitive.